# Нужно объяснение сортировки подсчетом

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, структуры-данных

Может кто-то доступно объяснить алгоритм сортировки подсчётом(не в конкретном языке программирования,а в абстрагированном варианте). Читаю книгу Томаса Кормена "Алгоритмы вводный курс". Дошёл до сортировки подсчётом. ну уже наверно раз 20 перечитал в том числе и пример. не доходит. я не знаю. может перевод такой или я)

Comment: так может напишите что непонятно?

Comment: Да в принципе  всё не понятно.. Как  он работает, что собственно в нём происходит.. вроде бы в книге по минимому математики,но все эти j-1, i от 0 до  m-1,где-то от 1 до n, одна процедура вытекает из другой,одни ключи сортировки должны быть меньше  значения(какого значения?),другие равны ему или больше.. и ещё стопятьдесят циклов в цикле.. меня просто  в ступор вводит всё это

Answer (score 3):

Попробуем наглядно представить происходящее. Предположим, у нас есть числа:

```
17 26 48 26 17 17 50 32 26 17 48
```

Генерируем из них массив A[i] = N, в котором эти числа являются индексом, а значением N является количество вхождений каждого числа в начальный набор:

```
A[17] = 4
A[26] = 3
A[32] = 1
A[48] = 2
A[50] = 1
```

Теперь просто идём по этому массиву (в естественном порядке его индексов) и выводим индекс массива N раз:

```
17 17 17 17 26 26 26 32 48 48 50
```

Comment: В такой реализации, как сказали вы, теряется связность. Например, если бы сортировались не числа, а какие-нибудь структуры (ну сортировка бы шла по какому-нибудь целочисленному параметру), то записать этот объект M раз было бы неправильно.

Comment: Александр, сортировка подсчётом применима только к числам.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 2):

Идея алгоритма заключается в подсчёте кол-ва каждого элемента и использования этой информации (а также диапазона значений элементов) для сортировки последовательности.

пример:

```
N = 10
A[N] = [4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

диапазоном каждого числа от `[0, 5]`

1) Создаётся допольнительный массив С размером K = 6 (верхняя граница диапазона значений (5) + 1) для хранения количеств каждого элемента

```
K = 6
C[K] = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

2) Перезаписываем элементы массива A следующим образом

```
for (i = 0, c = 0; i < K; ++i)
{
   for (j = 0; j < C[i]; ++j)
   {
      A[c++] = j;
   }
}
```

Сама "процедура" сортировки происходит во внутреннем цикле, тело которого выполняется столько, сколько раз число `i` встречается в последовательности `A` 
А так как в этом цикле в `j` меняется от `0` до `C[i]` с шагом 1, то после выполнения этого и всех слелующих таких циклов в массиве A будут только отсортированные числа и никакие другие ...

Собственно, ключевой особенностью это алгоритма является то, что имея сравнительно малый с кол-вом элементов последовательности диапазон значений можно получить почти линейную от диапазона значений `O(K)` скорость работы засчёт малых итераций внешнего цикла.

Comment: А почему дополнительный массив  имеет размер 6,6й элемент ограничитель?

Comment: и почему у вас во внешнем цикле 2переменные и с равно нулю?

Comment: Можете объяснить как работают 2эти цикла

Comment: 6 потому что последний элемент под индексом 5, так как я предпологал что индексация от нуля

Comment: Вам необходимо вдумчиво прочитать мой ответ, так как все ответы на ваши остальные вопросы есть в ответе

Comment: Я вас понял,спрошу только последнее.. можно ли обойтись без переменной «с» во внешнем цикле?

Comment: Можно вынести за цикл эту переменную но не внутрь

Answer (score -2):

Ответ на комментарий прошлого ответа:

Вы сказали, что сортировка подсчетом применима только к числам. Да, это так. Но я ведь ничего другого и не сказал. Я сортирую числа в структурах. Но кто мне мешает сортировать вместе с числами и объекты?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct foo
{
    foo(int A, int C) : a(A), c(C) { }
    int a;
    char c;
};

void countingSort(vector<foo*> &a, int n, int num)
{
    num++;
    int *b = new int[num];
    vector<foo*> c(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) b[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) c[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b[a[i]->a]++;
    for (int j = 1; j < num; j++) b[j] += b[j - 1];

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    {
        c[b[a[i - 1]->a]] = a[i - 1];
        b[a[i - 1]->a]--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = c[i + 1];
}

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    vector<foo*> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new foo(rand() % 100, rand() % 26 + 'A');
        cout << '[' << a[i]->a << ", " << a[i]->c << "] ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    countingSort(a, n, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << '[' << a[i]->a << ", " << a[i]->c << "] ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Неясно, какое отношение имеет к базовому алгоритму Ваше желание сортировать вместе с числами объекты...